# Does Apple reject my app if i store my Account and password in SQLite?

Tags: ios, app-store

My product will store the user's login credentials in SQLite when they enters it. I just want to know whether Apple rejects my App or not if i store the credentials in SQLite database

Comment: NO apple doesn't reject. But for security reason you have to sore credential in encrypted format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes You Can But As here you storing the credential and for this Apple also provides Keychain services to store secure data. View the documentation [Keychain Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html) As this documentation provides the basic Keychain Services functions in iOS like .

- Add an item to a keychain
- Find an item in a keychain
- Get the attributes and data in a keychain item
- Change the attributes and data in a keychain item

And Please review the [Sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html) for developer provided by Apple as this sample code shows how to add, query for, remove, and update a keychain item of generic class type.Here is some useful information for developer.

**NOTE :**

Apps that are built for the simulator aren't signed, so there's no `keychain access group`
for the simulator to check. This means that all keychain items are in the same default access group and all apps can see all keychain items when run on the simulator.

Comment: So i can upload the app even though i store the login details in sqlite?

Answer (score 2):

No, your app does not be rejected, but i have to ask - why do you want to do this? You have perfectly clear solution (keychain) - this is how you may use it: http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html

Comment: So i can upload the app even though i store the login details in sqlite?